# How to pass parameter in axios instance dynamically?

Tags: reactjs, axios, redux-toolkit

I am trying to pass token that comes from Redux store in an axios instance(**useRequest**). I want to pass the token while I am calling the instance

**requestMethod.js**

```
import axios from "axios";
const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:5000/e-mart/";
//Declaring a function to pass the Token dynamically.
export const userRequest =(TOKEN) => axios.create({ 
      baseURL: BASE_URL,
      header: { token: `Bearer ${TOKEN}` }, // Here the token comes dynamically
    });
```

**Products.js**

```
import { userRequest} from "../requestMethods";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

const {accessToken} = useSelector((state) => state.user.currentUser);//accessing token from redux store

useEffect(() => {
  const abortController = new AbortController();
  const getProdcuts = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await publicRequest.get(
        `products`,
        { signal: abortController.signal } // Here is where i want to pass the token from redux stroe
      );
      setProducts(res.data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
  };
  getProdcuts();

  return () => {
    abortController.abort();
  };
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If token is dynamic, don't pass it while create axios instance

// Axios instance

```
export const userRequest =(TOKEN) => axios.create({ 
  baseURL: BASE_URL
})
```

// how to call with different dynamic tokens

```
await API.patch('products',
  { signal: abortController.signal },
  {
    headers: {
      token: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`,
    },
  },
```

);